# Crosstab on Salesforce VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have been trying to get a wrappe class and aggregate function to product a crosstab type out for a customer VF page

```
Make    Type    Price
Ford    Saloon  100
Ford    Hatch   200
BMW     Saloon  400
BMW     Hatch   500
BMW     Estate  600
```

and the required output should be a table similar to below

```
        Saloon  Hatch   Estate
Ford    100     200 
BMW     400     500     600
```

is this possible to do in apex/visualforce?

I tried:

```
public List<AggregateResult> getRCLicenseTypes12(){
  List<AggregateResult> aggRes = new list<AggregateResult>();
  List<String> Results = new List<String>();

  aggRes = [Select Product_Name__c, Grouping__c, GROUPING(Product_Name__c) gProd, GROUPING(Grouping__c)gGroup, MIN(Unit_Cost__c) minCost
  FROM CSS_Products__c 
  WHERE Active__c = True AND Type__c = 'LicenseRC' AND Term__c = '12 months' 
  GROUP BY CUBE(Product_Name__c, Grouping__c) 
  ORDER BY GROUPING(Product_Name__c), GROUPING(Grouping__c)];

  system.debug('JMM aggRes: ' + aggRes);

  for (AggregateResult ar: aggRes) {
    system.debug('JMM aggRes1: ' + ar.get('Product_Name__c'));
    system.debug('JMM aggRes2: ' + ar.get('Grouping__c'));
    system.debug('JMM aggRes3: ' + ar.get('minCost'));
    //Results.add(String.valueof('<tr><td>'+ar.get('Product_Name__c'))+'</td><td>'+String.valueof(ar.get('Grouping__c'))+'</td><td>'+String.valueof(ar.get('minCost'))+'</td></tr>');
    Results.add(String.valueof(ar.get('Product_Name__c'))+String.valueof(ar.get('Grouping__c'))+String.valueof(ar.get('minCost'))+'</td></tr>');
  }
  return aggRes;
}
```

but I am not sure how to use the results. Tried looping over but it just produced a typical list of results, not cross-tabbed.

Think this is close but cannot see the way to get the results into a VF page

Comment: Welcome to sfse, Have you already tried developing this, or is there a reason why you believe this is not possible ? It's a lot easier to answer and help out, if it's clear what you've already tried and where you have gotten stuck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have been trying a wrapper class along with an aggregate result query. However this was producing multiple columns and not grouping on the Make from example

Comment: Including and sharing your code may give us more insight.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY CUBE aggregate query, or you'll need a two dimensional map-- take your pick.

Comment: Samuel - I was really asking if it is was possible to do this rather than what am i doing wrong.
GROUP BY CUBE seems to offer the solution i was looking for, will look into that and see if it works.
Thanks both